# passing data from controller to placeholders of the view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm getting set of data by calling a GET method in angularjs.

**controller**

```
    $scope.edit = function (id) {

                var edit_url = 'http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/api/restApiController/editQuestion.json?question_id=' + id;

                $http.get(edit_url)
                        .success(function (data) {
                         console.log(data);

                        })
                        .error(function () {

 })

 };
```

Data from the GET method is like follows

[image]

How can I pass the data into respective fields in my view (into placeholders, as this view is used to edit existing data)

**view**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="questionEditCtrl">

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name='quizAdd' ng-submit="submit(data)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="question">Question:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" ng-model="data.question" placeholder="Enter Question">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer1">Answer 1:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer1" ng-model="data.ans1" id="answer1" placeholder="Enter Answer 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer2">Answer 2:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer2" ng-model="data.ans2" id="answer2" placeholder="Enter Answer 2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer3">Answer 3:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer3" ng-model="data.ans3" id="answer4" placeholder="Enter Answer 3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer4">Answer 4:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer4" id="answer4" ng-model="data.ans4" placeholder="Enter Answer 4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer5">Answer 5:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer5" id="answer5" ng-model="data.ans5" placeholder="Enter Answer 5">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="sel1">Select Correct Answer:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.correct_ans" id="sel1">
                    <option>{{data.ans1}}</option>
                    <option>{{data.ans2}}</option>
                    <option>{{data.ans3}}</option>
                    <option>{{data.ans4}}</option>
                    <option>{{data.ans5}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st render all the answer & question by `ng-repeat` and then use `{{$index + 1}}` to show answer number inside place holder

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the response in array. Use ng-repeat to render you fields. What you perform ng-repeat, you can add placeholder like,

```
placeholder="Write Answer {{$index}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, populate a `$scope` variable with the data from the api for it to be available for binding in the template:

```
$http.get(edit_url)
     .success(function (data) {
         $scope.data = data; //populate a scope variable
     })
     .error(function () {
     });
```

Then, you can use one time expressions `::` for your placeholders as follows:

```
placeholder="{{::data.ans1}}"
```

This will ensure only the default value of `data.ans1` which was fetched from the api will be used as the placeholder. All subsequent changes to `data.ans1` will change the value, but the placeholder will remain the same.

Comment: I only get a empty field when using {{::data.ans1}}

Comment: Have you populated a scope variable with the data from the api? In your success handler, do $scope.data = data;

Comment: can you explain more please? i'm new to angularjs

Comment: I have done like you said.but still the same ,no value

Comment: Please, create a plunker then.

Comment: can you please take a look?